# SAPI5 Event returns 42 instead of 0

Tags: windows, sapi

I am using SAPI5 COM, and there is one event called

```
Word(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant, ByVal CharacterPosition As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
```

It works fine, but CharacterPosition starts off with 42, and I have no idea why it doesn't start off with 0 or 1.

The docu say:

CharacterPosition
    The character position in the input stream one character before the start of the word. In the case of the first word in a stream, this parameter is zero.

But for me, it always starts with 42, no matter which voice I use.

Does anybody know what might cause this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason:

The stupid SAPI5 engine takes the tags into account.